# Css style header ajax refresh with Wicket

Tags: css, ajax, header, wicket

Is there a way to ajax refresh a header component, css style,  with Wicket?

On an action from an user the application have to change the css-statements in the head of the page. Currently I am using a WebMarkupContainer with a wicket:head section and a CssContentHeaderItem, but that does not seem to get it done.

Comment: If you are overriding the stylesheet reference in the header you have re-render all components affected by the stylesheet change.

Comment: it is actually inline css, not a reference to a css file

Comment: I am not completely clear on your application, however I use `AttributeModifier` or `AttributeAppender` to update the css on a specific component.  i.e.- to apply a `selected` css to a div (with `wicket:id="container"`, I would put `container.add(new AttributeModifier("class","selected"));` then refresh the component.  I guess I handle it by changing the css tag on the component while keeping the css reference static.  Maybe some code and/or more explaination of what/why your are changing the css could help someone formulate a more useful answer.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Why change the css statements? I assume you are changing certain css-classes to make sure everything with the class 'label' is now green instead of red (or every '' tag is now green instead of red).

Why not simply add a different css-class to the component and keep both classes in the generated css?

That said, I believe adding a component to an ajaxrequest (`AjaxRequest#add`) will also call the `renderHead` method for that component.